# Run-time error on .Listbox.Rowsource = ""

Tags: excel, vba, memory, listbox

Excel sometime throws me the following error :

> Run-time error '-2147024882 (8007000e)':
>
> Could not set Rowsource property. Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

on a `.ListBox.RowSource = ""` instruction.

```
Private Sub reset_listbox_proposition_UF4()

    With UserForm_4_RADIATEURS
        With .ListBox_propositions
            .RowSource = ""              '<---- HERE !!
            .Clear
            .BackColor = couleur_Gris
            .ColumnHeads = False
        End With
    End With

End sub
```

This sub is used very often but only crashed once in a while, after a specific sequence of events. I managed to reproduce this error and noted that :

- `.RowSource` was already set and pointing to an existing worksheet
- Excel was using around 250,000K of *Working set memory* with a peak at 293,000K (according to task manager) on a PC with 8Go of RAM.

What's even stranger is that :

- If I skip to the next instruction (`.Clear`), this instruction will also fail
- If I then jump back to `.RowSource = ""` (after trying `.Clear`), it succeeds !

I don't get why it's failing and moreover why only once in a while and/or after some sequences. Any ideas?

**Notes**

- This macro is a big `XLAM Add-In`.
- I'm using `.RowSource = ""` and `.Clear` because the ListBox can be set using either `.RowSource = "Liste_propositions!A2:S" & nb_X` or `.List = Array_Propositions`. It's seems like Excel isn't very happy with that...

**Edit : Memory available to Excel**

I ran some test using this basic sub and incrementing X :

```
Dim myArray() As Double
ReDim myArray(20000, X)
```

I got Excel to use over 2,300,000K of *Working set memory* (with X = 13400).

So I'd say that insufficient memory/RAM isn't really the problem in my macro, since it throws the error while Excel is using less than 300,000K.

Comment: Changing your code isn't going to help with your 1GB RAM. Time to buy some more.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, But I doubt  it's really a memory issue since  -- this very simple `Sub` is not supposed to use much memory (while other deals with big 2D-Arrayq) -- I don't have memory issues except on that very instruction -- when it happens, Excel is using 210 000K of memory and only 4.90Go/8 are used on my machine according to Windows task manager

Comment: Can you free up some memory before calling this `Sub` ? Nullifying large objects can vastly improve performance. Same goes for unnecessary sheets, formatting (including conditional), cells, etc.

Comment: @dadler, As said above, I doubt this is really a memory issue. If ever it was, resetting the ListBox should rather free some memory than consume a bunch. I'm pretty sure VBA is unhappy with the RowSource vs Clear instructions...

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, I edited the post with some more info on a test I ran regarding memory. I'd confirm RAM isn't the problem...

Comment: I can't reproduce the Error on my end. Have you tried `.RowSource = Empty ` ?

Comment: @dadler. See the answer, the problem seems linked to the existence of the Ws referenced in the current value of `.RowSource`. Also, from memory, I don't think `Empy` is allowed (while `vbNullString` is).

Comment: @Tibo. Thanks for the update! . I didn't get any errors when testing with `.RowSource = Empty` . Glad you could resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems that Excel cannot update the `.Rowsource` property if its current value points to a deleted `Worksheet` :**

It looks like the problem comes from the Worksheet referenced in `.Rowsource` having been deleted prior to `.Rowsource=""`. In fact, I was able to reproduce the "*Run-time error... Not enough storage...*" just by deleting this `Ws`.

Moreover, in this macro, the referenced `Worksheet` is being deleted but also recreated before the `.Rowsource=""` instruction (which didn't help with pinpointing the problem).

=> While the `.Rowsource` property is set using the `Ws.Name`, Excel seems to use a strict reference (`.Codename` ?) to the `Ws`.

**Edit**
Running sone additional test on a fresh workbook/userform confirms that the Listbox will no longer work if the worksheet referenced in Rowsource is deleted, even if I recreate immediately an identical worksheet.